# Why my JTable row is not selected at first click?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Why my JTable row is not selected at first click? It is selected every time after first click. What is the problem?

I need to get all the values from the row which is clicked. Here is my code. It works well from second click.

```
 private void tblAccountInfoMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
  try {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblAccountInfo.getModel();
        txtUserName.setText(model.getValueAt(tblAccountInfo.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
        try {
            txtPassword.setText(model.getValueAt(tblAccountInfo.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

        }
        try {
            txtType.setText(model.getValueAt(tblAccountInfo.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

        }
        try {
            txtUrl.setText(model.getValueAt(tblAccountInfo.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

        }

        updateId = tblAccountInfo.getSelectedRow();
        btnSave.setEnabled(false);
        btnUpdate.setEnabled(true);
        btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aiobe) {
        aiobe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code ...

Comment: can you answer a question like this with so few information? i guess no... provide something we can work with

Comment: posted code is working (if my guess as how it is used is correct) - the problem must be elsewhere. Note: **do not use MouseListener consider using a ListSelectionListener!** Note2: you should not be using Exceptions for flow control, thath, normally you don't catch NullPointerException or ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - check for `null` and for the correct index,

Comment: Thanks. Now I am using ListSelectionListener instead of MouseListener and I remove the drag drop table and added a table which is not dragged drop using netbeans. Now everything is working fine. Thanks again